# LEA error in x86 assembly language

Tags: assembly, x86-16

I wrote a code to calculate the average of array elements in 16-bit x86 assembly language. It works correctly for `32h` and `C8h` elements but when I put `190h` an error occurs in `LEA si, array`. Why?

The first 2 bytes of the array represents array size.

I use emu8086.

```
data segment

array db 32h, 00, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9, 3, -10, 7, 14, 9


min db ?
max db ?
msg_average db 'The average = $'
msg_min db 'The minimum element is: $'
msg_max db 'The maximum element is: $'    
xxh dw ?
xxl dw ?

ends

stack segment
    dw   128  dup(0)
ends 

code segment 

start:

lea ax, data
mov ds, ax
mov es, ax

;Getting array size
lea si, array ;     HERE IS THE ERROR
mov cx, [si]
;Moving si to the location of the first element 
mov si, 0002h
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can you show the code when you try to use 0190h size?

Answer (score 1):

Using the LEA instruction you can only load the offset of a variable, not the segment!

For the segment you'll have to use the MOV instruction like this:

```
mov ax, seg data
```

Unfortunately the syntax for the "seg" keyword is different in different 8086 assemblers so the syntax will probably different in your assembler.

Comment: How? I'm not loading a segment offset! array is a variable. And I said that the code run correctly with small numbers of elements,

Comment: Ok. Maybe your assembler will translate "data" into "seg data" - my one does not. How do you exactly write the "array db ..." line in the case of 190h elements? "array db 90h, 1, ..." or "array db 190h, ...". The second one is wrong, of course. And what exactly is the error that happens? And shouldn't it be "add SI, 2" instead of "mov SI, 2" - you want SI to point to the 3rd byte of "array"?

Comment: I'll come back later. Sorry but I have to go.

Comment: MASM and TASM translates "data" as a segment value if "data" is the name of a segment, as in this example, so `mov ax,data` ; `mov ds,ax` is correct for these two assemblers. For NASM, it's `mov ax,seg array` instead.